# What is the story structure called when someone doesn't know they have the solution to their problem in hand?

Tags: fiction, plot

Perhaps the "classic" example is Dorothy in the Wizard of Oz. Early in her journey through the land of Oz, she acquires the slippers that she needs to take her back to Kansas. But she doesn't realize this until she is told at the very end, which is why she tries "other means" of achieving her goal.

What is this story structure called?

Comment: Abuse by a sadist. The "good" witch of the north is a sick puppy.

Comment: @TheThom No, she's being a parent or teacher. *Giving* a kid the answer is not nearly as useful as *helping* the kid to figure out the answer on her own. She'll remember it a lot better that way.

Comment: +1, it appears you thus far have the audience stumped.

Comment: @StuW: Someone answered a similar question here. http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/19136/are-there-stories-where-characters-are-supposed-to-grow-into-another-character. I was hoping they could answer this one.

Comment: A cautious (but appreciative!) -1; I'm not sure of the utility of taxonomic questions of "name this trope" or "name this structure," if they aren't associated with a practical difficulty of some kind.

Comment: @Standback: With all due respect, I find a taxonomy potentially useful because I want to do further research on the particular genre. Also, it could help others on the site if they want to discuss e.g. "Tom's circular story novel." Having the appropriate name makes both these applications more doable.

Comment: Tom: My concern is twofold. One point is, I don't see any use in trying to use Writers.SE as a poor substitute for what TV Tropes already does admirably well. (For example, I found my answer below with a quick skim of TV Tropes' page on "Wizard of Oz.") This concern may be misplaced; if you're looking for academic resources, the tongue-in-cheek TV Tropes names may not be very useful.

Comment: The second issue is that I just don't know if there ARE established, widely accepted taxonomy resources for tropes in academia. (If they aren't in widespread use, they're just as unhelpful as TV Tropes.) I'm not familiar with such resources - does anybody have any examples to give?

Comment: VoT gave me a very good answer about a "circular story structure" http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/19136/are-there-stories-where-characters-are-supposed-to-grow-into-another-character that I can use for future questions (or answers). SE is supposed to be a "canonical" site for knowledge in the various fields. Even the fact that "there are no known references" could be helpful. Another (investment) site I belonged to named something the "Chowder Rule" after its greatest proponent.

Comment: We're sliding into deep Meta territory here, but: there's a big difference between providing a canonical answer, and providing *an* answer, and then declaring it canonical.

Comment: Let me rephrase this, then: Does TV Tropes give you what you're looking for? If not - why not?

Comment: @TheThom: You're referring to movie version. In the original (book) version, the (old)  good witch of the North gives the slippers to Dorothy, but it is the young good witch of the SOUTH who explains their significance.

Comment: I don't think the names on "TV tropes" are, in general, widely accepted and recognized names for these ideas. Very few sound like the sort of names that literature professors give to such ideas, so I doubt they would be respected in an academic paper. Frankly, I often hear people ask "the name" of some complex idea, or even "the word", and I think the reality is that there are many ideas that do not have a single, recognized name. You have to describe them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only term I came across (in my brief search) was **self-realization drama**. It can cross genres but perhaps seems best suited for fantasy. It's the classic "I knew I had the power within me" kind of story.

Comment: This was in contrast to __self-discovery__ which seemed to be involving religion or sexuality.

Answer (score 3):

This is less of a story structure and more of a trope. (You can have very different story structures *leading up* to that final revelation.) Also, I don't know how many story structures actually have established names :P

Tropes don't always have established names either, but TV Tropes calls this ["It Was With You All Along"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItWasWithYouAllAlong).